# Equations containing series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have 3 equations to solve, all of which contain series:

1: Define $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if
$$\frac{1}{21} + \frac{1}{77} + \frac{1}{165} + \cdots + \frac{1}{16n^2 - 8n -3} = \frac{n}{24189}$$
What bothers me about this that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the first elements of the series aren't valid, so I'm pretty sure the problem is erroneous, but I thought I'd ask about it anyway, maybe I'm missing something.

2: Solve the following equation:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{2015}-1\right) + \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2x}{2015}-1\right) + \cdots + \frac{1}{2015}\left(\frac{2014x}{2015}-1\right) = x+1$$
I guess determining a partial sum for the series, calculating for 2015 and solving the equation would work, but I wasn't able to determine a partial sum formula.

3: Solve the following equation on the set of rational numbers:

$$\frac{x^{2015}+1}{2} + \frac{2x^{2015}+1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{nx^{2015}+1}{n+1} = n$$
The addition of the $x^{2015}$ parameter throws me, but I'm sure the restriction to $\mathbb{Q}$ helps solve that. I tried to find a formula for partial sum here as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If the first question is indeed misprinted, it is likely that the correct version should be $$\frac{1}{21} + \frac{1}{77} + \frac{1}{165} + \cdots + \frac{1}{16n^2 \color{red}+8n -3} = \frac{n}{24189}$$

In which case we would have a telescoping sum, and would solve$$\frac 14\left(\frac{-1}{4n+3}+\frac 13\right)=\frac{n}{24189}$$
$$\Rightarrow n=\color {red}{2015}$$

The second question gives a similarly- themed answer:

Grouping the terms together, it can be written as
$$\frac{x}{2015}\left[\frac 12+ \frac 23+ \frac 34+...\frac{2014}{2015}\right]-\left(\frac 12+\frac 13+...+\frac{1}{2015}\right)=x+1$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{x}{2015}\left[1-\frac 12+1-\frac 13+1-\frac 14+..+1-\frac{1}{2015}\right]-\left(\frac 12+\frac 13+...+\frac{1}{2015}\right)=x+1$$

Now writing $$S=\left(\frac 12+\frac 13+...+\frac{1}{2015}\right)$$
We have
$$\frac{x}{2015}(2014-S)=x+1+S$$
$$\Rightarrow2014x-Sx=2015x+2015+2015S$$
$$\Rightarrow-2015(S+1)=x(S+1)$$
$$\Rightarrow x=\color{red}{-2015}$$